# Rewriting polytop as polyhedron

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, polyhedra

> Given $P=conv(v_1....v_m) \subset \mathbb R^n$ How can I find the matrix and vector $A\in R^{m,n}, b\in R^m$ such that $P=\{x\in R^n: Ax\le b \}$ using the polar set of $P$

Would appreciate any help or hints

Edit: $Ax\le b$ means $(Ax)_j \le b_j$

Comment: This problem is called the Facet Enumeration Problem, and it is equivalent to the Vertex Enumeration Problem. A wide variety of algorithms that have been developed for it. Are you looking for a brute force, proof-of-concept approach, or do you want to optimize the computational complexity in some way?

Comment: @Kajelad : I am given a certain polytop and I have to rewrite it as a polyhedron only using the polar set of $P$